# printf and echo -n Work Differently - Why?

Tags: bash, function, echo, printf

#### echo -n

```bash
my_function() {
  echo -n "$@"
}

my_function hello world
```

I get my desired output:

```bash
hello world
```

---

#### printf

```bash
my_function() {
  printf "$@"
}

my_function hello world
```

I get only the `hello`. Where is the `world`?:

```bash
hello
```

---

---

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The first argument to `printf` should be a format string, normally containing specifiers like `%s` to tell it what to do with the remaining argument(s) - since you haven't provided such, the remaining arguments are ignored and the format string is printed verbatim.

Comment: @steeldriver ahh bruh I feel so stupid, of course... How did I forget about that^^ Thanks :)